# making a variable only settible through its set property

Tags: c#

I have a boolean variable, I want every change to its value to invoke a piece of code.

my current solution is the following:

```
bool _manualControl;
bool manualControl {
    get {
        return _manualControl;
    }
    set {
        this._manualControl = value;
        GlobalEventManager.ManualControlEvent?.Invoke(value);
    }
}
```

this solution has two problems:

1. the value of "_manualControl" can be changed internally without invoking my piece of code, I want to prevent that.
2. I would prefer to avoid using two variables to get the desired behavior.

Is there any way to achieve what I want while avoiding these two specified issues?

Comment: Are you talking about Property?
e.g. 
private bool ManualControl {
  get{...}
}

Comment: You can't avoid the variable \_manualControl to be set, since it has the same protection level as your property. You could _mark_ it with a tripple slash comment, where you explain, that the property must be set instead of the variable. But to be honest.: Why should somebody set the variables value instead of the property's?

Comment: "I would prefer to avoid using two variables to get the desired behavior." You already only have one variable (field). You have one field, and one property.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the property to be `public` and have a `private` backing field that can only be modified from within the class, which you have control of.

Or you could use an Aspect Oriented Programming framework like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/), which would allow you to use an auto property and annotate it with the behaviour you desire. This would remove the need for you to have a backing field.

Comment: Having a private field doesn't prevent it from being assigned directly without triggering the setter logic, by the code inside the class

Comment: @felix-b The idea is the OP controls the class.

Answer (score 4):

To me this sounds a bit like you want to solve an architectural problem, aka code smell. Why is it that you fear your field might be set outside your setter? Is it a particularly large class that a lot of people are chaning without really knowing what it is doing?

Why even have code in the setter? Like you could just redesign your code to have a method do what your setter code does and introduce that into your code flow / process.

And have a Unit Test validate your desired behavior.

Comment: My coworkers have a tendency to exploit the access level of fields and use them in unintended ways.

Comment: @Fuseques Then give your fields random names, that are not predictable by your co-workers ;-)

Comment: @Fuseques use git and pull requests and code reviews. explain and educate. you will never be able to solve this only in code. you can bypass a lot of other supposedly safe secure mechanisms via reflection so don't even try to hide information. again, perform code reviews and educate.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to:

- ensure that the setter code always executes when a new value is assigned (inside and outside of the class)
- avoid having two members in the class, that represent a single value

Then this can be approached by wrapping the value within a struct like one below:

```cs
struct Intercepted<T>
{
    private readonly Action<T> _onChange;
    private T _value;

    public Intercepted(Action<T> onChange, T initialValue = default(T))
    {
        _onChange = onChange;
        _value = initialValue;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            _onChange?.Invoke(value);
        }
    }
}
```

In the class, `ManualControl` can now be represented with a single member, of type `Intercepted<bool>`:

```cs
public Intercepted<bool> ManualControl { get; } = new ManualControl(
    onChange: newValue => {
        GlobalEventManager.ManualControlEvent?.Invoke(newValue);
    }
);
```

The value can be accessed like this:

```cs
// from within the class
if (ManualControl.Value) { ... }

// from outside
myObj.ManualControl.Value = true;
```

Now there is no way to change the value without triggering the setter code, both inside and outside the class.

Comment: Thats a fancy way of putting the same code somewhere else, but not preventing his coworkers from adding additional properties to this struct that bypass his setter. I don't think theres a way to solve this problem in code in any way that cannot be bypassed. So why even try.